# Denormalizing Data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, algorithms, interpolation, polynomial

I am applying **Polynomial Regression** to my data, however the parameters theta were always **=0**,
i noticed that my y data or output is too large in the order of 100000 so i **normalized y**, i got very good predictions.
However what can i do if i need to get the predictions based on the **real y values**, meaning how can i **denormalize** ? wont the parameters be wrong afterwards somehow since i got them off of the normalized data ?

Note: i also normalize my input x data

Comment: You should explain *exactly* what you intend by "normalize", since it seems to get used in (at least) three different senses. Precisely what did you do to normalize your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most techniques for "normalization" are invertible. If you think of your normalization procedure as a function $f$, this means we can find a function $f^{-1}$ such that $y = f^{-1}(f(y))$. This means you can apply $f^{-1}$ to your predicted value to get back to the original "unnormalized" scale, or denormalize the output using your parlance. Here's some common ones.

[Standard score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score)
$$
\begin{align*}
f(y) &= \frac{y - \mu}{\sigma}\\
f^{-1}(y) &= \sigma y + \mu
\end{align*}
$$
[Scaling [0,1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling)
$$
\begin{align*}
f(y) &= \frac{y - y_\min}{y_\max - y_\min}\\
f^{-1}(y) &= y (y_\max - y_\min) + y_\min
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: This is exactly what i ended up doing